# Hamburger menu and nav links not aligning properly when applying media query

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, web

I created a hamburger navigation menu for a device with max-width: 500px with the below code:

```
   @media only screen and (max-width:500px){
    label{
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    menu{
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .menu{
        display: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaeb;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #toggle:checked + .menu{
        display: block;
    }
        }
```

and the when i display the output my 'Free Trial' link ends up below the hamburger icon as shown in the image. How do i get this menu to be displayed as a block of links.[Nav Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s55t.png)

Comment: Can you please provide the html as well?

Comment: Your `label` element and `menu` do not have a period before them, you have to indicate if it's a class or id, unless it's the element `label` you're styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason you're running into problems is because of the wrong syntax:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:500px){
        .label{ display: block; cursor: pointer; }
        .menu{ display: block; text-align: center; width: 100%; }
        .menu{ display: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaeb; margin: 0; }
        #toggle:checked + .menu{ display: block; }
    }
```

Add the period before `label` and `menu`